# Limit variable length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit a variable. If it contains more than 300 letters, it should be trimmed, so that there are ONLY 300. Is there any way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: That's a pretty zen question. Just use javascript: `s.substring(0,500)`

Comment: Yeee, jQuery is the answer to any question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [pure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) JavaScript:

```
myVar = myVar.substring(0, 300);
```

Comment: Not enough jQuery: `myVar = $.map(myVar.split(""),function(val,i){ if(i<300) return val; }).join("");` (Seriously though, +1.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I have extended your version to be twice more jQuery: `myVar = $($.map(myVar.split(""), function(val, i) { if (i < 300) return $("<i />").html(val); })).text()`.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has two native methods for this...

```
string.substring(from, to)

variable_name = variable_name.substring(0,300)
```

and

```
string.substr(start,length) 

variable_name = variable_name.substr(0,300)
```

both of them should do the trick.

**Edit:** as @freakish suggested

```
string.slice(beginslice, endSlice)

variable_name = variable_name.slice(0,300)
```

Note: `substring` and `slice` are roughly the same, except `slice` can accept negative indices (relative to the end of the string), where as `substring` can't. Also, `substr` takes length as its 2nd parameter.

Comment: +1 for `substr`. You can also use `splice`. And a benchmark: http://jsperf.com/substring-vs-splice

Comment: JavaScript has _three_ native methods for this, `.slice()` being the other. I assume that's what @freakish meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assume really_long_string is over 300 characters long
var really_long_string = "abcdefg..."

// Your new string, truncated to fit your desired length
var shortened_string = really_long_string.substring(0, 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery - just using substring in JS should do the trick

```
var originalString = 'This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... This content is more than 300 characters... ';

document.write(originalString.substring(0, 300));
```